# Running Threads In a Java EE Application

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, server

I am constructing a Java EE application that creates a large amount of threads that manipulate data. Is there a way to create these threads on a separate server than the one my application is Hosted on? Then Have My application server set up to simply access this other (Thread) server to get the data from the thread at a time specified by the user. I am very concerned about scalability of my web application.

Comment: Why not create a services server with its own JVMs running (with their own threads), then you can communicate between your application and services server in countless ways.

Comment: Threads live within their parent processes

Comment: @Kon that sounds like an exact solution! could you a send me a link to some documentation on the subject

Comment: @J.Dutch I recommend first reading up on Java RMI, which is a common way for a JVM to communicate (invoke a method in) another JVM. I don't have a particular article to recommend as I learned this stuff on-the-job, but I'm sure there are a lot of good resources out there.

Comment: @Kon thank you. I believe that this is exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct, but this sounds like you might be reinventing the wheel and possibly using the wrong tools for the job (i.e. JEE servers). Perhaps you should look into software systems which are designed to handle large and complex algorithms using clustered environments. The sort of stuff used for SETI and the genome projects for example. I would imagine there are a lot of complexities around this area such as synchronisation and load balancing, problems which others will have already addressed.

Comment: >I am very concerned about scalability of my web application -- Why are you very concerned? Have you measured the throughput you get when you do it in a standard way and are not satisfied with it?

Answer (score 2):

In an Java-EE Application you shouldn't create/run threads by yourself. That is the responsibility of the application-server.
Besides that, it is a bad idea to start an infinite number of threads simultaneously. This can easily bring your server to his knees.

You should instead consider using a message-queue. As java-ee compliant application-servers do implement JMS - they already have a message-queue implementation build in. E.g. if you are using JBoss - the JMS-Implementation is [HornetQ](http://hornetq.jboss.org/) and I believe since wildfly they've moved to [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

This would also solve your second problem: running your threads - or in this cease your message-queue - on a separate server or even in a cluster of servers - because you can publish messages to remote message-queues either using JMS or AMQP protocol.
If you're running your message queue on a separate server, you don't even need an application server for the queue. You can run a standalone queue. In this case I would recommend [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).